# SQL Foreign and Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This may be a dumb question, but I am really new to `SQL database` and I would like to create a `SQL database` that contains 2 tables, for example;

**Table 1:**

```
AccountID,

AccountUsername,

AccountPassword,
```

Account ID would be the primary key.

**Table 2:**

```
AccountID

Calculation

TotalCalculation
```

AccountID would be the foreign key.

Everytime I update the **AccountID** in Table 1, it does not show data for AccountID in Table 2, I'm really new to database and I don't know is it possible to do or not.

What I would like to achieve is:

**Table 1:**

```
AccountID = 1;

AccountUsername = 'TestUsername'

AccountPassword = 'TestPassword'
```

**Table 2:**

```
AccountID = 1; - This is updated whenever I update the AccountID in Table 1.

Calculation = 123.123

TotalCalculation = 1234.1234
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you INSERT a new row into T1, you need to INSERT a row with the same AccountID into T2.

Comment: What's the Primary kEY ON TABLE2?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that @Strawberry, but there would be a column called CalculationID which would be the primary key for table 2.

Comment: Note that an Edit button is provided - and see if you can provide a more comprehensice example. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Is `AccountID` the primary key of table 1? If so, you should never update it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically update the accountid in table2 when you update it in table1 then create a FK on table2 with an on update cascade clause for example

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t
(accountid int primary key);

create table t1
(accountid int,
foreign key fk1(accountid) references t(accountid) on update cascade
);

insert into t values (1),(2);
insert into t1 values (1);

update t
    set accountid = 3 where accountid = 1;

select * from t;
+-----------+
| accountid |
+-----------+
|         2 |
|         3 |
+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

select * from t1;
+-----------+
| accountid |
+-----------+
|         3 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

if  You want to update default calculation and total calculation when an account is created 
Add Trigger to table 1 to add/update the account in table2.